# Can I have a section in the CV for entering professional certifications?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

This seems to be a section that is missing currently from the CV details.  Any plans to add this?  Even though I know it's not really the most important thing to have listed as a part of one's career accomplishments it would be nice to optionally include this.

Comment: Any workaround you people use? Put it as Personal Statement/Experience /Education?

Comment: In the meantime, you could add certifications to the Education or Background fields.

Comment: Saul, we’ve added this. It’s pretty straightforward, hopefully it serves your needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We’ll do something like this.  We need to think a bit more on how exactly it should be presented, but obviously it is very important for certain jobs / industries.  In the meantime,  adding them [under education](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122325/146719) seems like a good workaround.

Edit: This has been implemented, you’ll find it right under Education.

Answer (score 12):

I agree, this would be a good additional information.  The Server Fault people will appreciate this even more.

Answer (score 8):

**Microsoft certifications**

As many people will like to show these on these CVs, it would be good if everyone show then in the same way.

Each exam, has:

- A number
- The title
- The date on which it was passed
- (There is no grade)
- a set of tags for what the exam covered

Then there are the overall certifications (e.g. MCSD) that each has:

- a icon
- date passed,
- name

Also we have certifications from other companies (e.g. Java etc), but I don’t know what data they have.

Should there be a section on the CV for certifications, or should one of the current sections be used.

Answer (score 6):

It would be nice to have a dedicated section for that, [like at LinkedIn profile](http://blog.linkedin.com/2010/10/18/linkedin-profile-sections/).

- Meanwhile, my certifications found home in the **"Education"** section of Careers CV:
  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUvi7.jpg]

Given that I learned quite a bit to obtain certifications, placing them into *Education* feels quite natural.

> Heck, given my past experience in job hunting I sometimes feel that learning / education was *one and only* useful thing about certifications. At job interviews, nobody bothered to ask about how I scored in this and that exam - all they were interested in was solving programming puzzles and API details.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to see it as an autocomplete field.

Answer (score 2):

This was asked almost two years ago. Any word on this? I currently have one certification and am planning on getting another in the next couple of years. Adding this to my Careers CV as something other than a footnote would be really nice.

Comment: Check out gnat's suggestion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122325/155160